# Context Menu on TreeViewItem Calls TreeViewItem's Method?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, contextmenu, treeviewitem

I have a `TreeView` setup so that each `TreeViewItem` has right-click context menu applied as a `Style`. Something like:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="contextMenu">
         <MenuItem Header="Save"  IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Saveable}"/>
         <MenuItem Header="Copy" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Copyable}"/>
         <MenuItem Header="Remove" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Removeable}"/>
    </ContextMenu>
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource contextMenu}" />
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```

Saveable, Copyable and Removeable are properties that come from the object that's used as the `TreeViewItem`.

What I'm looking for is when the user clicks on a `MenuItem`, it would click on the appropriate method of the selected object. So clicking on the "Save" `MenuItem` would call `object.Save()`, "Copy" calls `object.Copy()`, etc.  But I'm not sure what the syntax would look like, or whether the idea is actually acceptable in terms of typical WPF style. I know I can just create a new event handler in the encompassing window, but I'd prefer the selected item itself to handle the event.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think that there is an automated way of doing this. The closest option would be to setup a `RoutedUICommand` for each item in the `ContextMenu`, and then create a `CommandBinding` for each in your class. If you want those to go to the `TreeViewItem`, you'll probably need to subclass `TreeViewItem` and set up the `CommandBindings` there.

The one option that I thought might work would be to add an `EventSetter` for `MenuItem.Click` to the `TreeViewItem` style. However, that did not work - probably because the items in the `ContextMenu` are in a different visual tree from the `TreeViewItems`.